# Requirement for Script or AWS CLI to copy specific folders from Amazon S3 to SharePoint

Tags: amazon-web-services

We are having requirement from one of user , to copy specific folders from Amazon S3 to MS SharePoint. Requesting your suggestions on this. Also please let us know if there is way to copy specific folders from S3 to local drive.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy directly from S3 to SharePoint.

You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to download files/folders from Amazon S3 to your local drive. You could then upload them to SharePoint:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my-bucket/folder1/ ./folder1/
```